# In the Disney movie WALL-E why did the ship's computer fight the captain?

Tags: plot-explanation, wall-e

In the movie WALL-E all humans have left Earth aboard a massive space ship because Earth has basically been turned into a giant unlivable trash pile. When WALL-E and his friend EVE discover a small plant growing on earth they bring it to the massive space ship to essentially show the humans it is time to return to Earth. However, when the computer finds out EVE possesses the plant, it decides to try and destroy the plant.

Basically I am wondering why? Why does the computer decide to seemingly break its programming and fight the captain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the computer was [told to do so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WALL-E).

> EVE brings the plant back to Captain McCrea, who watches EVE's recordings of Earth and concludes that they must return. However, AUTO refuses, revealing his own secret no-return directive A113, issued to BnL autopilots after the corporation concluded centuries earlier that the planet could not be saved. He mutinies, tasering WALL-E and deactivating EVE and throwing them both down the garbage chute, then detaining the Captain.